# Random colour generation

Tags: java

I want to generate randomly one of three colours, either red,blue,white. I want to create a program that randomly generated one these colours to a person when after they enter their name in java. The purpose of the program would be for the user to enter a name and the out put would be that" name is assigned to *either red, blue, or white*"

Comment: have you tried putting them in an array and generating a random integer between 0 and the length of the array?

Comment: Pseudo-code: `color = { 'red','blue','white' }[Math.random() * 3]`

Comment: Please write some code and show it to us. You are downvoted because you haven't demonstrated the requisite effort to get help.

Comment: Okay thank you for your input. I'm a fairly new to coding, but just started using this website. So yeah thanks, I did put up a picture for you to be able to see were I am at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array:

```
String[] colors = {"red", "blue", "white"};
```

Generate a random number between 0 and 2:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int random = rand.nextInt((2 - 0) + 1);
```

Get the random color:

```
String randomColor = colors[random];
```